# What's the most straight forward way to show that a function is increasing?

Tags: functions, logarithms, gamma-function

I am trying to show that:

$$\frac{2}{n}\log\Gamma\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) - \log\Gamma\left(\frac{x+n-1}{n}\right)$$

is an increasing function for $x \ge 5$ and $n > 2$

One way to do this would be to show that $\frac{x}{2} > \frac{x+n-1}{n}$ since:

$n(x-2) > 2x-2$

and then using $\frac{\Gamma'}{\Gamma}(s) = \int_0^{\infty}\left(\frac{e^{-t}}{t} - \frac{e^{-st}}{1 - e^{-1}}\right)dt$ to show that for $x \ge 5$, $n > 2$:

$$\frac{\Gamma'}{\Gamma}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) - \frac{\Gamma}{\Gamma}\left(\frac{x+n-1}{n}\right)=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{1-e^{-t}}(e^{-\frac{x+n-1}{n}t} - e^{-\frac{x}{2}})dt > 0$$

Is this the best way to show this?  Is there a better way?

Thanks,

-Larry

Comment: One would have to start with proving that the derivative is nonnegative. So, I think your way is the best way to show this.

Comment: Thanks very much!  I thought that this was very straight forward but I wanted to make sure that it appeared that way to others.